# Where and how are this icons made?

Tags: games

Are this vector icons? I'm working on a game and I want to make icon to learn technique how it's made, but so far I'm not sure how to make especially that glossing effect.

[image: icons]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good approach to learning a technique is to start by breaking down how another artist did it. The style above can easily be found on any of the large graphic asset markets. [Creative Market](https://creativemarket.com/), [Graphic River](http://graphicriver.net/), and [Pixden](http://www.pixeden.com/) are a few of the bigger ones.

Searching "game candy" on Creative Market quickly turned up many similar assets as the one you have. [Here is an example](https://creativemarket.com/TopVectors/324551-Bright-cartoon-candies-for-game).

Comment: Thank you Benjamin, I just don't know why so many people down voted me, I just asked a question because I'm not the best at it, I find some tutorials online so they will be great "starting" point.

Comment: No problem! The more you practice - the better you will get. Having a direction is great inspiration to encourage you to work. Keep at it!